# Social application with users and sessions

Tags: php, object-oriented

I work with a legacy application. This is my attempt to add some sanity in an new feature I want to add.

It's a social application with users, sessions etc. The entire application is run in a procedural fashion. It still uses MySQL, so once this feature is complete, upgrading to PDO will be my next project.

```
class Groups {


    protected   $_db;
    protected $member_id;

    protected $group_id,
                      $group_title,
                        $group_about,
                        $group_join_us,
                        $group_contact,
                        $group_rss_url,
                        $group_rss_post_limit,
                        $group_privacy;

    protected $group_super_admin;

    protected $group_approve_status,
                        $group_approve_date;

    protected $group_meta_title,
                        $group_meta_description,
                        $group_meta_keywords;


    public function __construct($db, $member_id) { 

        $this->_db = $db;
        $this->member_id = $member_id;
    }

    /** 
     * Set the group title
     *
     * @param str $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_id($group_id) {

        $this->group_id = $group_id;    

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group title
     *
     * @param int $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_id() {

        return $this->group_id; 

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group title
     *
     * @param str $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_title($group_title) {

        $this->group_title = $group_title;  

    }

    /** 
     * get the group title
     *
     * @return int $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_title() {

        return $this->group_title;

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group about
     *
     * @param str $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_about($group_about) {

        $this->group_about = $group_about;  

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group about
     *
     * @param str $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_about() {

        return $this->group_about;  

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group join us
     *
     * @param str $group_join
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_join_us($group_join_us) {

        $this->group_join_us = $group_join_us;

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group join us
     *
     * @return str join us content
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_join_us() {

        return $this->group_join_us;    

    }


    /** 
     * Set the group contact
     *
     * @return str $group_contact
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_contact($group_contact) {

        $this->group_contact = $group_contact;  

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group contact
     *
     * @return str $group_contact
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_contact() {

        return $this->group_contact;    

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group rss
     *
     * @param str $group_rss
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_rss($rss_url) {

        $this->group_rss_url = $rss_url;    

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group rss url
     *
     * @return str $group_rss
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_rss() {

        return $this->group_rss_url;    

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group rss post limit
     *
     * @param int $group_rss
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_rss_post_limit($group_rss_post_limit) {

        $this->group_rss_post_limit = $group_rss_post_limit;    

    }

    /** 
     * get the group rss post limit
     *
     * @return int $rss_post_limit
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_rss_post_limit() {

        return $this->group_rss_post_limit; 

    }


    /** 
     * Set the group description
     *
     * @param str $group_description
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_description($group_description) {

        $this->group_description = $group_description;  

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group description
     *
     * @return str $group_description
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_description() {

        return $this->group_meta_description;   

    }


    /** 
     * Set the group keywords
     *
     * @param str $group_keywords
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_keywords($group_keywords) {

        $this->group_meta_keywords = $group_keywords;   

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group keywords
     *
     * @return str $group_keywords
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_keywords() {

        return $this->group_meta_keywords;  

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group meta title
     *
     * @param str $group_keywords
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_meta_title($group_meta_title) {

        $this->group_meta_title = $group_meta_title;    

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group meta title
     *
     * @return str group meta title
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_meta_title() {

        return $this->group_meta_title; 

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group meta title
     *
     * @param tinyint bool 0 / 1 
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_approve_status($group_approve_status) {

        $this->group_approve_status = $group_approve_status;    

    }

    /** 
     * save group status
     *
     * @param tinyint bool 0 / 1 
     * 
     */
    public function update_group_approve_status($group_approve_status) {

        $sql = "UPDATE `groups` SET
                        `approved`  =   ".sql_c(intval($group_approve_status)).",
                        `date_approved` = NOW()
                        WHERE
                        `id`    =   ".sql_c($this->group_id)."";    
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$this->_db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        $this->set_group_approve_status($group_approve_status);

        return $result;

    }


    /** 
     * Get the group meta title
     *
     * @return str group meta title
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_approve_status() {

        return $this->group_approve_status; 

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group super admin
     *
     * @param int $super_admin_id
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_super_admin($super_admin_id) {

        $this->group_super_admin = $super_admin_id;

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group super admin
     *
     * @return int super admin id
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_super_admin() {

        return $this->group_super_admin;    

    }

    /** 
     * Set the group group privacy
     *
     * @param int $private_group
     * 
     */
    public function set_group_privacy($group_privacy) {

        $this->group_privacy = $group_privacy;

    }

    /** 
     * Get the group privacy status
     *
     * @return int group privacy
     * 
     */
    public function get_group_privacy() {

        return $this->group_privacy;    

    }


    /** 
     * save new group
     *
     * @param 
     * 
     */
    public function insert_new_group() {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `groups` SET
                        `added_by_member_id`    =   ".sql_c($this->member_id).",
                        `date_added`                    = NOW(),
                        `super_admin_id`            =   ".sql_c($this->member_id).",
                        `private_group`             =   ".intval($this->group_privacy).", ## All groups are private by default
                        `title`                             =   '".sql_c($this->group_title)."',
                        `about_us`                      =   '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->group_about)."',
                        `join_us`                           =   '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->group_join_us)."',
                        `contact_us`                    =   '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->group_contact)."',
                        `rss_url`                           =   '".sql_c($this->group_rss_url)."',
                        `rss_post_limit`            =   ".sql_c($this->group_rss_post_limit).",
                        `meta_title`                    =   '".sql_c($this->group_title)."',
                        `meta_keywords`             =   '', ##keywords can come later
                        `meta_description`      =   '".sql_c($this->group_description)."'
                        ";  
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$this->_db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        $group_id = mysql_insert_id();

        $this->set_group_id($group_id);

        return $result;

    } 

    /** 
     * build existing group by id
     *
     * @param str $group_id
     * 
     */
    public function fetch_group_by_id($group_id) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE `id` = ".sql_c($group_id)."
                        AND (`temp` != 'on' OR `temp` IS NULL)
                        AND (`backup` != 'on' OR `backup` IS NULL)";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$this->_db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        $list = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $this->set_group_id($list['id']);

        //set all group properties from this group
        $this->set_group_title($list['title']);

        $this->set_group_about($list['about_us']);

        $this->set_group_join_us($list['join_us']);

        $this->set_group_contact($list['contact_us']);

        $this->set_group_rss($list['rss_url']);

        $this->set_group_rss_post_limit($list['rss_post_limit']);

        $this->set_group_description($list['meta_description']);        

        $this->set_group_keywords($list['meta_keywords']);

        $this->set_group_meta_title($list['meta_title']);

        $this->set_group_approve_status($list['approved']);

        $this->set_group_super_admin($list['super_admin_id']);

        $this->set_group_privacy($list['private_group']);



    }   



    //$group_contact
} //EO class Group
```

This being my first steps into *OOP?* I would appreciate some basic advice and tips. My problem is that, although I understand the OOP syntax, its hard for me to build anything practical with it.  Maybe it's just lack of experience.

Comment: found some great tips here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/help-improve-my-first-php-class, Ill keep this post up in case someone wants to review it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are most certainly on the right path, and as a first step, it's very good. Some pointers for the future.

- **Don't use `mysql_*`** - I know you said you're already planning to. I'm mainly saying this for future users.
- **Objects work best with other objects** - If you have groups, it makes sense to have a `User` class, etc.
- **Code style** - Make sure your spacing and indentation are uniform throughout the file, and throughout the application in general.
- **Naming** - By the name `Groups` I understand that this class is a collection of single `Group` objects, that doesn't seem to be the case, so this class should be called `Group`.
- **Separation of concerns** - Your `Group` shouldn't know where it came from. It shouldn't be aware of the database, or know how to fetch itself. Another object, `GroupMapper` should be responsible for that, and have methods like `fetchGroupDetails($group)`.

None of the above issues are critical (except for `mysql_*` maybe), you're doing a good job!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will keep those points in mind as I expand this feature.